# How can I get JPA/Entity Manager to make parallel queries instead of lumping them into one batch?

Tags: java, jpa, servlets

Inside the doGet method in my servlet I'm using a JPA TypedQuery to retrieve my data.  I'm able to get the data I want through an http get request method.  The method to get the data takes roughly 10 seconds and when I make a single request all is good.  The problem occurs when I get multiple requests at the same time.  If I make 4 request at the same time, all 4 queries are lumped together and they take 40 seconds to get the data back for all of them.  How can I get JPA to make 4 separate queries in parallel?  Is this something in the persistence.xml that needs set or is it a code related issue? 
**Note:** I've also tried executing this code in a thread. 
A link and some appropriate terminology to increase my understanding would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
try{
    String sequenceNo = request.getParameter("sequenceNo");
    EntityManagrFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mydbcon");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Myeo> returnData = methodToGetData(em);
    System.out.println(sequenceNo + " " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    String myJson = new Gson().toJson(returnData);
    resp.getOutputStream().print(myJson);
    resp.getOutputStream().flush();
}finally{
    resp.getOutputStream().close(); 
    if (em.isOpen())
            em.close();
}
```

4 simulaneous request samples
localhost/myservlet/mycodeblock?sequenceNo=A
localhost/myservlet/mycodeblock?sequenceNo=B
localhost/myservlet/mycodeblock?sequenceNo=C
localhost/myservlet/mycodeblock?sequenceNo=D

resulting print statements
A 38002
B 38344
C 38785
D 39065

What I want
A 9002
B 9344
C 9785
D 10065

Answer (score 0):

If you do 4 separate GET-requests these request should be called in parallel. They must not be lumped together, since they are called in different transactions.

If that does not work as you wrote, you should check whether you have defined a database-connection-pool-size or a servlet-thread-pool-size which serializes the calls to the dbms.

Comment: Thank you very much for the direction aschoerk.   I was directed to another project for some time and I forgot to reply.  I'm sure my issue is in your second point.  Once I've returned to this and resolved the issue I suspect I'll be awarding you the answer.